# apperyio, ionic5, input[type=file], load image asset to the image

Tags: ionic5, appery.io

I'm trying to load an image from the **input[type=file]** to the image on a page.
Is it possible to do it **without** uploading a file to the database?

[More info about what i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nn40R.png)

Comment: ` <input type="file" (change)="onFileInput($event)" />` and ..ts file `onFileInput(event: any) {
    let file = event.target.files[0]; let file url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
}`

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot. Ill post a ready solution in below for others.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution for this, i've got with a help of Ravi(thanks to him).

1 Create a "fileURL" variable.
[How to do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWbG7.png)

2 On image set "src" attribute with value of "{{fileURL}}".
[How to do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dSeK.png)

3 Click on "file" and add "change" evet -> run typescript, with code  [How to do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Jfac.png):

```html
//event.target.firstChild - is an input.
let file = event.target.firstChild.files[0];

if(file)
    this.fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
```